# Parametrizing the curve of intersection between a elliptic cylinder and a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spheres, parametrization

How can I form the parameterization of a curve of intersection given a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 =1$ and an elliptic cylinder $2x^2 + z^2 = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @WillJagy$${x={\cos t\over \sqrt 2}\\y={\cos t\over \sqrt 2}\quad ,\quad  t\in \Bbb R\\z=\sin t}$$and $${x={\cos t\over \sqrt 2}\\y=-{\cos t\over \sqrt 2}\quad ,\quad  t\in \Bbb R\\z=\sin t}$$
**Comment**

My original answer suggested just one of those branches while there are two. The images below suggest why:

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is also a piece with $y=-x$

Comment: I think it just determines the direction of recursion on the intersection but I agree with you. A parametrization is not unique even as with the unit circle we have $$x=\sin u\\y=\cos u$$or$$x=\sin u\\y=-\cos u$$

Comment: $( \frac{- \cos t}{\sqrt 2} , \;  \frac{ \cos t}{\sqrt 2} , \; \sin t  )$ also solves, there are just two intersection points, $t = \pm \pi/2$ They are two ellipses, they cross twice

Comment: Even with the answer I am not sure how you are supposed to calculate this problem.

Comment: You are quite right. I edited the answer. Thanks....